# Can I submit a user-defined search term as one of several possible search field types using python and beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There is a website which accumulates data about amateur sports teams and their players' stats. You can put in the players ID number, and the site will return a page for that player, and on that page you can navigate to a 'stats' page for them and view their stats.

The problem is that this is very slow and tedious to do in-game (ie for an announcer) to reference player stats. The stats are also arranged quite poorly with no user control over what you see and how you see it. It's basically a big table of numbers in font size 12, very difficult to reference accurately at a glance.

I'd like to write a basic program that I can load all the games player ids into at the start of the game, with each of them being a GUI button. This part I can do fine on my own. Then when I want quick stats for a particular player, I can click on their ID number, and the script will parse it as a search term for the website, then nav to their stats, and return the stat values, which I'll then filter to produce only the relevant ones (for example, stats for that player and for the classification of game they're playing) This I can also do fine.

The website in question has a static URL when it returns results, the URL doesn't change from one page to the next, so I can't simply generate URLs from the ID number and nav to it, in a browser it kicks me back to a blank search form.

Therefore I think my last option is to use some sort of web scraping tool to actually submit the ID number as a search term, then on the subsequent results page, navigate to a particular element (the "Details" button) and then to a second tab in the results (The "Stats" tab). I have a working knowledge of Python, but I've never used it for web scraping, and I've never used Beautiful Soup before today. I'm also not super familiar with HTML and search forms, or how they work.

I'd been following along a video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxAX4UgJd8k&t=288s

but I was a bit lost when they started talking about search terms, that was kind of glossed over.

Here is as far as I got with the code (not far):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'http://mycricket.cricket.com.au/pages/search.aspx?mode=2'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

And inspecting the ID search field and the "Search" button gives me this HTML:

[image]

[image]

And I'm not quite sure how to proceed to drop in the ID number to be searched, and submit it to get a results page.

Any advice or insight would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Not really helping with the search question, but it seems that you can just visit http://mycricket.cricket.com.au/common/pages/public/rv/cricket/viewplayer.aspx?playerid=1234567 and get the site you want.
(Also, to save loading time, I would advise you to load the data from the website before the game and not in real-time, because on my machine the site needed around five seconds to load)

Comment: The site has a tendancy to 'lock' you to a particular club, and then looking up two players from two different clubs requires that you first change clubs, then look up the player. It's also not always possible to know which players will attend ahead of time, or have their ID numbers provided ahead of time. Also, players can be associated with more than one club, so you might have the wrong club selected, when you get stats, and they will be incomplete or not relevant. Id much rather just use fixed urls for players, but that doesn't seem doable.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a link with search results for a particular player and (more or less) your desired output?

Comment: Here is, for example, a players stats overall: http://mycricket.cricket.com.au/common/pages/asphost.aspx?loc=/cricket/reports/playercareerbatting.asp&playerid=605007&eid=4000, however each gridline for grade per season links to season-specific stats for that grade, which is more in line with what I might want, but I have no way of knowing what grades/seasons have stats without seeing an overview first: http://mycricket.cricket.com.au/common/pages/public/rv/cricket/viewplayer.aspx?locx=PLY&playerID=605007&eID=4000&entityID=4000&seasonID=65